# perl: naming hash variables read from YAML

Tags: perl, yaml

I'm reading some information from a `YAML` file

**`groceries.yaml`**

```
# comment
fruit:
   apples: 1
   oranges: 1
   grapes: 1
vegetables:
   potatoes: 1
   onions: 1
   leeks: 1
```

into a `perl` script

**`myscript.pl`**

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use YAML::Tiny;

# Create a YAML file
my $stuff = YAML::Tiny->new;

# Open the config
$stuff = YAML::Tiny->read( 'groceries.yaml' );

print "Fruit: ", %{($stuff->[0]->{fruit})},"\n";
print "Vegetables: ", %{($stuff->[0]->{vegetables})},"\n";

exit
```

This works fine, but I would like to have one hash for `fruit` and one for `vegetables`. My naive attempt was

```
my @keys = keys %{($stuff->[0])};
foreach my $key (@keys){
        my %{ $key }  = %{($stuff->[0]->{$key})},"\n";
}
```

but clearly this doesn't work.

I'd love to understand what I'm doing wrong, and am open to different work flows that accomplish the same idea `:)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this :

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use YAML::Tiny;
use Data::Dumper;

# Create a YAML file
my $stuff = YAML::Tiny->new;

# Open the config
$stuff = YAML::Tiny->read( 'groceries.yaml' ); 

my %fruits = %{ $stuff->[0]->{fruit} };
my %vegetables = %{ $stuff->[0]->{vegetables} };
```

I don't know why you put some parentheses in your code :

```
%{($stuff->[0]->{$key})},"\n";
```

I think this is the problem.

---

To iterate over the HASHes,

```
use Data::Dumper;
# ...
foreach my $key (keys %{ $stuff->[0] }) {
    print Dumper $stuff->[0]->{$key};
}
```

---

### Edit2

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use YAML::Tiny;
use Data::Dumper;

# Create a YAML file
my $stuff = YAML::Tiny->new;

# Open the config
$stuff = YAML::Tiny->read( 'groceries.yaml' );

my %top_h;

foreach my $key (keys %{ $stuff->[0] }) {
    $top_h{$key} = $stuff->[0]->{$key};
}

print Dumper \%top_h;
```

Comment: +1 yes, indeed this works- I apologize for not writing that I had this solution in the question. In the actual example there will be lots of other hashes (`dairy`, `clothes`, etc), so I'd like to do it using a loop if possible

Comment: This looks very promising =) I can't seem to access `%fruit` or `%vegetables` though? Have I missed something?

Answer (score 2):

This solution enables you to access `%fruit` and `%vegetables`. They are declared as package global variables using `our` so that they will be in the symbol table, which then allows you to do use symbolic references or glob assignments. You'll also need to turn off `strict refs` to enable this. Also see [this reference](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlref.html#Symbolic-references).

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use YAML::Tiny;
use Data::Dumper;

my $stuff = YAML::Tiny->read('groceries.yml');

my %groceries = %{$stuff->[0]};

our %fruit;
our %vegetables;
{
    no strict 'refs'; 
    #no strict 'vars'; # don't need above 'our' declarations with this
    while (my ($key, $val) = each %groceries) {
        %$key = %$val;
        # or *$key = $val;
    }
}

print Dumper \%fruit;
```

If you don't know the keys upfront, then you'll also need to turn off `strict vars` so you don't need to declare the hashes before assigning to them. But then you might get a warning when you use the hash directly.

But having said all of that, I think it would be simplest to just use `%groceries`.

Answer (score 1):

```
my ( $fruit, $vegetables) = @{$stuff->[0]}{ qw<fruit vegetables> };
```

If you want to do this in a loop, first, I would save the first "document" to a local reference.

```
my $yaml = $stuff->[0];
```

And then in a while loop, do this:

```
while ( my ( $k, $v ) = each %$yaml ) {
    say ucfirst( $k ) . ': ' . %$v;
}
```

You could also use [`List::Pairwise`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?List%3a%3aPairwise) and do this:

```
mapp { say ucfirst( $a ) . ': ' . %$b } %{ $stuff->[0] };
```

Comment: +1 thank you, yes this works. I apologize for not specifying in the question that there will be a lot of other `hashes` too, so I'd like to do it using a loop if possible :)